# ASP.Net Core 2.0 not a selectable option

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to create an ASP.NET core empty project from template. In the wizard, I select an empty project but the drop down does not contain Core 2.0

[image: Drop down]

I have installed the sdk

[image]

I tried this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119362/core-20-templates-not-listed.html without success

I have no dotnet in the Path variable. Should I? The link talks about having multiples.

Comment: Update your visual studio to the latest?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.7.1

Comment: looks like windows 7. Maybe it does not work on older versions of windows now? It makes sense

Comment: I updated to 15.7.1 Enterprise and it is now available. However a curious thing happened. I had version 15.2 (pro). I went to Help->register product to see if i could see a license key in case i needed to uninstall. There was an update button available that said it would move me to 15.7. So I pushed it. The outcome was a side by side install of enterprise (15.7) and pro (15.2). I am not exactly sure how that occurred and now the button is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fix the original problem on visual studio 2017 15.2 (pro). Per David's recommendation I updated to 15.7 and 2.0 now appears.